# Removing trailings zeros in string

Tags: ruby

I have a string and I need to remove trailing zeros after the 2nd decimal place:

```
remove_zeros("1,2,3,4.2300")  #=> "1,2,3,4.23"
remove_zeros("1,2,3,4.20300") #=> "1,2,3,4.203"
remove_zeros("1,2,3,4.0200")  #=> "1,2,3,4.02"
remove_zeros("1,2,3,4.0000")  #=> "1,2,3,4.00"
```

Missing zeros don't have to be appended, i.e.

```
remove_zeros("1,2,3,4.0")     #=> "1,2,3,4.0"
```

How could I do this in Ruby? I tried with converting into `Float` but it terminates the string when I encounter a `,`. Can I write any regular expression for this?

Comment: What kind of string is this and where do the trailing zeros come from?

Comment: Cary Swoveland and Stefan, I have updated the comment now, I meant to say last trailing zeros not last two zeros.

Comment: @Gopal all trailing zeros or just trailing zeros after a `.`? And I'm still curios, what kind of string / number format is this?

Comment: I assume that "4.0000" is to be converted to "4.0", not "4.". Correct?

Comment: Cary swoveland If it is 4.0000 it has to be 4, It is 4.0200 then it has to be 4.02.

Comment: Could the string be "1,2,3,4.0"?  If so, what should `remove_zeros("1,2,3,4.0")` return?

Comment: If it is the case, then it has to be left out as it is. Only if when I have 1,2,3,4.0000 or more zeros it has to be resulted as 1,2,3,4.00

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First, you need to parse the string into its component numbers, then remove the trailing zeros on each number.  This can be done by:

1) splitting the string on ',' to get an array of numeric strings

2) for each numeric string, convert it to a Float, then back to a string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def parse_and_trim(string)
  number_strings = string.split(',')
  number_strings.map { |s| Float(s).to_s }.join(',')
end

p parse_and_trim('1,2,3,4.2300') # => "1.0,2.0,3.0,4.23"
```

If you really want to remove the trailing '.0' fragments, you could replace the script with this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def parse_and_trim_2(string)
  original_strings = string.split(',')
  converted_strings = original_strings.map { |s| Float(s).to_s }
  trimmed_strings = converted_strings.map do |s|
    s.end_with?('.0') ? s[0..-3] : s
  end
  trimmed_strings.join(',')
end

p parse_and_trim_2('1,2,3,4.2300') # => "1,2,3,4.23"
```

These could of course be made more concise, but I've used intermediate variables to clarify what's going on.

Comment: Hi I don't want array as output, but your program helped me, I have included the join(',') function at the end

p parse_and_trim_2('1,2,3,4.2300').join(',')

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.  You could also move the `.join(',')` into the method, of course.

Comment: I've changed the code examples to return the string you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a regular expression could be used.

```
R = /
    \.     # match a decimal
    \d*?   # match one or more digits lazily
    \K     # forget all matches so far
    0+     # match one or more zeroes
    (?!\d) # do not match a digit (negative lookahead)
    /x     # free-spacing regex definition mode

def truncate_floats(str)
  str.gsub(R,"")
end

truncate_floats "1,2,3,4.2300"
  #=> "1,2,3,4.23" 
truncate_floats "1.34000,2,3,4.23000"
  #=> "1.34,2,3,4.23"
truncate_floats "1,2,3,4.23003500"
  #=> "1,2,3,4.230035" 
truncate_floats "1,2,3,4.3"
  #=> "1,2,3,4.3" 
truncate_floats "1,2,3,4.000"
  #=> "1,2,3,4."
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, but the last one is not the expected result of me, it has to be 1,2,3,4.

Comment: That makes the problem slightly easier (but it's a rather strange format). I fixed it.

Comment: Hi Cary, sorry to ask you again, Is it possible to bring this way? After decimal, I need two zeros, Is it possible? You have brought one single zero but I need two zeros.

Comment: Another variation: `str.gsub(/(\.\d{2,}?)(0+)$/, '\1')`.

Comment: @SergiiK Excellent, this is what I want.

Comment: Gopal, are you sure that's what you want? `"4.000".gsub(/(\.\d{2,}?)(0+)$/, '\1') #=>  "4.00"`, which contradicts your last comment on the question. Either you don't know what you want or you have not found a way to ask your question in a complete and  unambiguous way. You owe it to those who read your question in future to fix it.

Comment: @Sergil, you don't need the second capture group.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No no, the condition given in the question is clear, If it is 4.0000 then it has to be 4.00 If it is 4.0 then 4.0.

Comment: My example to which you are referring is `"4.000"`, not `"4.0000"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
> a = "1,2,3,4.2300"
> a.split(",").map{|e| e.include?(".") ? e.to_f : e}.join(",")
#=> "1,2,3,4.23" 
> a = "1,2,3,4.20300"
> a.split(",").map{|e| e.include?(".") ? e.to_f : e}.join(",")
#=> "1,2,3,4.203"
```

Comment: A problem. If `a =  "4.000"` you return `"4.0"`, but OP wants `"4."`. Yes, it's an odd requirement.

Comment: Cary swoveland, I am sorry, I stand corrected here, I need two zeros there. That was the mistake.

Comment: @Gopal : If `a = "4.000"` you need `"4.00"` ?

Comment: @Gopal your comments are contradictory. Edit your question and clarify what you need.

Comment: @Stefan Updated in the original question.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: @abarisone : yes sure I will update my answer when I get free